# How do I add a BoxCollider2D directly after removing a BoxCollider (3D) from a GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am instantiating a new game object with a Cube mesh. I'd like this to have a BoxCollider2D component.

I start by instantiating a new GameObject with a primitive using GameObject.CreatePrimitive. 'Creates a game object with a primitive mesh renderer and appropriate collider.'

```
GameObject inst = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
```

A default BoxCollider (3D) is attached. I do not want this, so I remove it.

```
Destroy(inst.GetComponent<Collider>());
```

This works and in the editor I can see that I now have a cube with no BoxCollider.

Now I try adding a BoxCollider2D

```
inst.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
```

The full method looks like this

```
private GameObject createSnakeCube()
    {
        GameObject inst = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        Destroy(inst.GetComponent<Collider>());
        inst.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        return inst;
    }
```

However. I will get the following error message

```
Can't add component 'BoxCollider2D' to Cube because 
it conflicts with the existing 'BoxCollider' derived component!    
UnityEngine.GameObject:AddComponent()
```

Does anyone know why Unity still thinks a BoxCollider is attached when none is visible in the editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Destroy()` will not immediately destroy the given object. It will mark it as to-be-deleted and will only delete all marked objects at the end of the frame as an optimization.

In your case you should use `DestroyImmediate()` which will immediately destroy the object, allowing you to add your new collider.